# NPM to deploy software

Tags: node.js, npm

I'd like to use NPM to deploy my NodeJS + ExpressJS websites (API rest + front).

What i'm doing for now :

1. I setup a private NPM repository
2. I push my software as a NPM package to this repository
3. I do npm install mysoftware
4. Now, the problem, I have to do : node node_modules/mysoftware/bin.js

After step 4. I have the following file tree :

```
.
└── node_modules
    ├── my-software
    │   ├── bin.js
    │   ├── package.json
    │   └── src
    ├── some-required-module
    │   ├── HISTORY.md
    │   ├── index.js
    │   ├── LICENSE
    │   ├── package.json
    │   └── README.md
```

I don't like this file tree because everything is a the same level : my software and its dependancies, it makes it very messy.
I'd like it to be this way :

```
my-software
├── bin.js
├── package.json
├── src
└── node_modules
    ├── some-required-module
    │   ├── HISTORY.md
    │   ├── index.js
    │   ├── LICENSE
    │   ├── package.json
    │   └── README.md
```

Is there a way to install an npm package as a project, and therefore have the file tree I'd like ?

Comment: Am if you using npm v3. Read this article. Npm v3 install all modules in node module directory. https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3 . What you want i think is older npm version like 2.

Comment: No, this article is about project dependencies. I want to deploy a full project AND its dependencies with NPM, but I don't want the said project to be in node_modules directory

Comment: You do understand that all npm modules installed into node_modules folder.  There is no way that they will become root of project. So you need to add my software into git. Run git clone your project and then do npm install. This will make tree as you wanted.

Comment: Mykola is right. Publishing your application as a npm package will result in this structure by design. Modules should be re-usable. If you want your project to serve as a base, don't publish it as an npm package but clone it as Mykola correctly suggested.

Comment: I'm surprised there's not more discussion about this here or in general out there.  Seems to be a fundamental flaw in npm.  And I'm surprised so many people as a solution use git to deploy.  Traditionally code version-control systems are not deployment tools. They're for source code control, not for distributing runnable production applications.